# How to filter list lines of a dictionary of lists according to a specific number?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, closest

I have a huge dictionary of lists that needs filtering.
Here's an example of its output:

```
d = {
    'hate': [(2310, "Experiencer: 'like hours'", 212, 222),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'two'", 1035, 1038),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 1560, 1566),
              (2310, "Experiencer: ' '", 1619, 1620),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'Tatooine'", 1726, 1734),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 1775, 1781),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'Master Qui-Gon'", 1863, 1877),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'half'", 1883, 1887),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'One'", 2114, 2117),
              (2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186),
              (2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487),
              (2310, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 2564, 2570),
              (2310, "Stimulus: 'Padme'", 2739, 2744)],
'confirmation': [(4132, "Experiencer: 'like hours'", 212, 222),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'two'", 1035, 1038),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 1560, 1566),
              (4132, "Experiencer: ' '", 1619, 1620),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Tatooine'", 1726, 1734),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 1775, 1781),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Master Qui-Gon'", 1863, 1877),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'half'", 1883, 1887),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'One'", 2114, 2117),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'One'", 2484, 2487),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2564, 2570),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Padme'", 2739, 2744),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2782, 2788),
              (4132, "Experiencer: ' '", 2818, 2819),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'centuries'", 3562, 3571),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'one'", 3585, 3588),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 3679, 3685),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Anakin Skywalker'", 3789, 3805),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Obi-Wan'", 4014, 4021),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Qui-Gon'", 4025, 4032),
              (4132, "Experiencer: 'Qui-Gon's'", 4100, 4109),
              (4132, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 4281, 4287),
              (4132, "Stimulus: ' '", 4355, 4356),
              (4132, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 4436, 4442)]}
```

Each key (one of them is `hate` as stated above) has a number at the beginning of every list element. Here, it's: `2310`.

I would like to be able to print out the **two** elements of the list that have a number that is closest to that number, being the next biggest, and the next smallest.

Example output:

```
'hate': [(2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186),
         (2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487)]
```

because

```
(2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186)
```

has the number `2180`, which is the next smallest one when compared to `2310`

and in return:

```
(2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487)
```

has the number `2484`, which is the next biggest one when compared to `2310`

I guess this needs a `for` loop? How do I iterarte over the dictionary of lists, compare the first, self-repeating number with the first numbers of every line and return the ones closest, as mentioned above?

I hope my question is understandable enough...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

Goal would be to automate the process of going through the dictionary, and update it by filtering it.

The desired output of that dictionary would be something like this:

```
 d = {
        'hate': [(2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186),
                 (2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487)],
        'confirmation': [(4132, "Experiencer: 'Qui-Gon's'", 4100, 4109),    
                         (4132, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 4281, 4287)],
...}
```

I also edited the above example of an output that I'm getting so far. It's a dictionary of lists

Comment: the poster is not wrong @JacobIRR - it is a dictionary of lists

Comment: @vasia oh I just realized the key was that first string.

Comment: You should also post your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: The data you have here appears to be sorted by that first varying number.  Is that always the case?

Comment: @Austin I tried another approach so far, of trying to split the two different labels to two different dictionaries, but it's still a work in progress.

Comment: @patrickhaugh yes, it is the index of the key, here `hate`. Each key has a unique index that repeats itself within the list as a first value. So, a comparison of that value at each key with the first number in the "tuple" at the end of a line, which are actually offsets of a character would give me the next smallest and next biggest. I noticed a pattern: Everytime the `Experiencer` list ends and the `Stimulus` one begins, it's those two lines that I always need. Example is in the question.

Comment: @Waldkamel "varying" means "changing". Your lists seem to be sorted by their third values already.  Is that just chance for this data, or is that always the case?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh ah, yes - indeed: it varies, or changes, when a new key is presented - I can post another example, if you'd like. In the function that created this dictionary states: if the third values are smaller than the index then label it as `Experiencer`, and if bigger, then label it as `Stimulus`- that's why they're already sorted. But I can't figure out how to just have the meeting points presented in the dictionary and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lists are already sorted, we can use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) to find the place between the "Experiencer" and "Status" entries:

```
from bisect import bisect

l=[(2310, "Experiencer: 'like hours'", 212, 222), (2310, "Experiencer: 'two'", 1035,1038), (2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 1560, 1566), (2310, "Experiencer: ' '", 1619, 1620), (2310, "Experiencer: 'Tatooine'", 1726, 1734), (2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 1775, 1781), (2310, "Experiencer: 'Master Qui-Gon'", 1863, 1877), (2310, "Experiencer: 'half'", 1883, 1887), (2310, "Experiencer: 'One'", 2114, 2117), (2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186), (2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487), (2310, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 2564, 2570), (2310, "Stimulus: 'Padme'", 2739, 2744)]

right_index = bisect(l, (2310, "F"))  # "F" comes between "Experiencer" and "Status" 
lower, higher = l[right_index-1], l[right_index]

print(lower, higher, sep="\n")

# (2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186)
# (2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487)
```

Then you can process your dictionary quite easily

```
from bisect import bisect

def get_boundary(l):  # This assumes all lists in your dict have at least 2 items
    if len(l) < 2:
        return l
    right_index = bisect(l, (l[0][0], "F"))  
    return [l[right_index-1], l[right_index]]

print({key: get_boundary(value) for key, value in d.items()})
```

produces

```
{'hate': [(2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186), 
          (2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487)], 
 'confirmation': [(4132, "Experiencer: 'Qui-Gon's'", 4100, 4109), 
                  (4132, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 4281, 4287)]
}
```

Comment: I edited my question for clarity. I would like to go through the whole dictionary, key for key and filter their sorted lists depending on the first, unique number that is representing the key in a way. I sadly can't do that for every list of the big dictionary.

Comment: @Waldkamel I'm pretty sure this does what you want.  This should be very quick, as it doesn't build any intermediate memory products, and uses binary search to traverse the lists.

Comment: I'm getting for some dictionaries of other files an `IndexError: list index out of range` - apparently there are lists that have only one item. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: You can check the length of the list in `get_boundary`.

Comment: I did just that, but it sadly still shows the same error message. Could it be, that there's even lists without items that could lead to this error message?

Comment: I edited my answer to account for that. Could there be some list that doesnt follow the Experiencer ... Stimulus pattern?

Comment: Snap, I just noticed by looking through the dictionary manually that some keys **do** have alternating index, as they show up multiple times in the text and get appended to the same key. That has to be the problem, right? So, with every change of the key's index, the loop starts again for `Experiencer` and `Stimulus`. So, it's not a problem of list-length.

Comment: Yet it worked for other dictionaries that had that same thing, but it considered only the first index, and ignored the rest, no matter how many came after for one key. Hmm...so what could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group all like elements from each of the list and then sort them (based on absolute difference) and get the first 2 elements

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> f = lambda t: t[0]
>>> {key:sorted(v, key=lambda t: abs(k-t[3]))[:2] for key,lst in d.items() for k,v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=f), f)}
{'confirmation': [(4132, "Experiencer: 'Qui-Gon's'", 4100, 4109), (4132, "Experiencer: 'Qui-Gon'", 4025, 4032)], 'hate': [(2310, "Experiencer: 'Anakin'", 2180, 2186), (2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487)]}
```

Comment: I think it's worth expounding on the choice of `key` that you are using for sorting here. Also `f` is undefined here.

Comment: @pault. Thanks.. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Sunitha I edited my question for clarity. I would like to go through the whole dictionary, key for key and filter their sorted lists depending on the first, unique number that is representing the key in a way.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most vanilla, simple way to do it (that I could think of). There is a solution below that uses `itertools` that is more elegant, but harder for a novice to understand.

If `l` is the list pointed to by `hate` in your dictionary:

```
target_num = l[0][0]
closest_smaller, closest_bigger = 0,0
closest_smaller_diff, closest_bigger_diff = float("inf"), float("-inf")
for element in l:
    for num in (l[-2],l[-1]):
        diff = target_num - num
        if diff > 0 and diff < closest_smaller_diff:
            closest_smaller = num
            closest_smaller_diff = diff
        if diff < 0 and diff > closest_bigger_diff:
            closest_bigger = num
            closest_bigger_diff = diff
print(closest_smaller, closest_bigger)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# let big_dict be the big list you start with
output_dict = {}
for key, value in big_dict.items(): 
    # break the list into two lists, for those with third value greater
    # and those with third value lesser/equal
    higher_tuples = [i for i in value if i[2] > i[0]]
    lower_tuples = [i for i in value if i[2] <= i[0]]
    # Get the values from that list with 
    high_closest = min(higher_tuples, key=lambda x: x[2] - x[0])
    low_closest = min(lower_tuples, key=lambda x: x[0] - x[2])
    # bind them into an output
    output_duct[key] = [high_closest, low_closest]
```

If you wanted you could bind it all together in one really big one-liner:

```
output_dict = {key: [min([i for i in value if i[2] > i[0]], key=lambda a: a[2] - a[0]), min([j for j in value if j[0] <= j[2]], key=lambda b: b[0] - b[2])] for key, value in big_dict.items()}
```

Comment: If you're going to commit to two scans over the list, why not `min((x for x in value if x[2] > x[0]), key=lambda n: abs(n[3] - n[0]))`, and the same for `x[2] <= x[0]`?

Comment: you're absolutely right, actually. I'll change that

Comment: Your answer is actually the closest one to what I'm seeking. Only thing is, it outputs somehow only two labels from `Stimulus`-label: The actualy `Stimulus` line that i'm seeking, but yet another random `Stimulus` line. Example output of your code to the example in my question: `{ 'hate': [(2310, "Stimulus: 'One'", 2484, 2487),
          (2310, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 8802, 8808)], 'confirmation': [(4132, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 4281, 4287),
                  (4132, "Stimulus: 'Anakin'", 8802, 8808)],}`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is

- Sort the list on the element of interest, position 2.
- Use a binary search to find where `2310` would appear in this list; you should be between two elements.  Those are the two elements you want.